# How to efficiently store and restore part of an object (a hash) in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, chess

I am extending [`Chess::Play`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Chess-Play), a little chess framework.  I want to implement a method that undoes a move.  In `do_move()` I save relevant state information for using it later to restore the state:

```
sub do_move {
    my ($self, $move) = @_;

    # Do some things and call the super method ...
    
    # Return everything needed for restoring the current state.
    return (
        BOARD => [@{$self->{BOARD}],
        CASTLE_OK => {%{$self->{CASTLE_OK}},
        COLOR_TO_MOVE => $self->{COLOR_TO_MOVE},
        # ... Other properties omitted for brevity.
    );
}
```

It is, of course, crucial to make *deep* copies of those properties that are not scalars.  The original author is doing more or less the same internally in other places.

In `undo_move()` I restore the state.  A shallow copy is enough because the state information is no longer needed.

```
sub undo_move {
    my ($self, $state) = @_;

    $self->{BOARD} = $state->{BOARD};
    $self->{CASTLE_OK} = $state->{CASTLE_OK};
    $self->{COLOR_TO_MOVE} = $state->{COLOR_TO_MOVE};
}
```

Alternatively, I could assign to a hash slice:

```
my @keys = keys %$state;
# Using just %$state on the right-hand side is a bug because
# it returns the values in arbitrary order.  Therefore a hash
# slice must be used although the entire state has to be copied
# back.
@{$self}{@keys} = @{$state}{@keys};
```

But is that really more efficient? Or will Perl internally make a shallow copy of `$self` for that, copying also the hash slots that I don't want/need to touch?

If using the hash slice *is* more efficient, would it then be better save the state in `do_move()` with something like this:

```
return Storable::dclone(@{$self}{qw(BOARD CASTLE_OK COLOR_TO_MOVE)});
```

It is key for this application that the code is efficient, not elegant or idiomatic, because it will be executed millions of times.

In reality my state information has 8 properties, one array of 144 integers, one array of 16 integers, one hash with 4 keys, one with two keys, and four scalars.

Yes, I should try out both versions and compare the performance.  I will do that.  But I am interested in what Perl is doing internally here and how to solve such problems in general.

Edit: Normally, chess engines do not save state but rather just undo the modifications to the board.  But that is more complicated than it looks at first glance because of castling and en passant captures.  My assumption is at the moment that the shorter the code, the faster it will be, so that most of it runs inside Perl's C code and is not interpreted as Perl bytecode.

Comment: A third option for restoring the state would be: `%$self = %$self, %$state` but that looks inefficient to me.

Comment: Do you need to return all properties to save the state, what seems to be the case, or just the three that are shown?  When restoring, again do you only need to copy those three or all of them?

Comment: @zdim The state is a subset of `$self` and contains all properties needed to undo the move, so that the internal board representation and all flags are restored to what they were before the move had been made.

Comment: OK, thanks ... I think I see now what's the issue

Comment: @zdim I need to slice `$state` in `undo_move()` even if I need all of it.  Otherwise the keys are not in the correct order.

Comment: "_need to slice `$state`..._"  -- yeah, got it (and edited my comment, sorry!)

Comment: There's also `%$self = ( %$self, %$state );`. The real question is why you aren't creating immutable states, then use `$self->{state} = $new_state;`, whether `$new_state` is a newly constructed state from `$self->{state}`, or a previous state to which to to return.

Comment: @ikegami a. See my first comment. b. I'm not sure whether I completely understand your suggestion. Do you mean that `do_move()`, instead of returning the state, should assign it to `$self->{state}`? And `undo_move()` should restore everything from `$self->{state}`? Or to not have the state properties on the top-level but move them all under `$self->{state}` so that `$self->{BOARD}` would become `$self->{state}->{BOARD}?

Comment: a. Your first comment doesn't add anything, and doesn't sound right. b. The key is that you never modify `$self->{state}->{...}`, just `$self->{state}`

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**   Added benchmarks. In short: the fastest way to copy (*this*) data is by copying items one by one. It is clearly faster than using a slice, and for this data much faster than using `Storable`.

---

I see two problems with copying data by hand, piece by piece

```
return (
    BOARD => [@{$self->{BOARD}],
    CASTLE_OK => {%{$self->{CASTLE_OK}},
    COLOR_TO_MOVE => $self->{COLOR_TO_MOVE},
    # ... Other properties omitted for brevity.
);
```

As for efficiency, this code manually dereferences and then constructs back arrays and hashes; no work is left undone, and all data gets copied. I don't see how it could be more efficient than the same job done by the fine tuned `C` code in `Storable`, regarded to be fast.<sup>†</sup>

More importantly, the code copies only "one-level-deep," so to say -- if the arrayref `$self->{BOARD}` has any *references* for values then there is a problem, and worse yet it'll be a quiet problem.  I assume that that is not the case here but it still leaves me itchy allowing for a potential bug, should that change (the proverbial 6 months later, naturally).

So in principle I'd readily go with `Storable`.<sup>†</sup>

---

However, there's a special case, as clarified in comments: there is absolutely no reason to worry about the depth of the copy as there can only be plain arrays and hashes; and, only a subset of the data structure is needed.

First, I don't see why a hash slice would be (measurably) faster than copying item by item; each key still has to be dereferenced, and its value copied over.  I don't know the implementation but I'd expect a "slice" to be a syntax feature, for which the work is done the way we do it manually.

While there may be some optimization with a slice, given that all used keys are known in that statement,  when you go key by key the slicing is done already since keys are given one by one.

On a million repetitions?  Measure. My gut feeling is that only copying by hand could be faster, but again by a faint measure. Or try

```
$self->{$_} = $state->{$_} for keys %$state;
```

to avoid constructing an array (`@keys`). The postfix-`for` loop (as a [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers)) has no scope built so that's another teeny-tiny benefit.

What leaves the question of how to return from `do_move`, and I'd still go for `Storable`. Even as there is some extra work of generating a slice the
<del>whole copying would have to be faster in that old `C` code.</del> — *nah, see benchmark -- One can't extract a part of a hashref but it has to be rebuilt and that voids possible advantage of the library, for this simple data at least.  (Worse, it turns out that manual copy is faster than `Storable` even for copying the whole hashref, by a factor of 2. The data here is so simple that "by hand" method has no work to do.)*

<del>I haven't measured any of this, and that will of course answer the question.</del> — *see benchmarks*

**Conclusion**

The data here is so simple that a manual copy is much faster than using `Storable`, so do as shown in the question. (And since one has to rebuild only a part of the hashref using `Storable` is even less effective.) But measure on real data.

Then, rebuild data to return (in `undo_move`) "by hand," see first benchmark below

---

**Edit**   This discussion *really* needs measurements. Here are basic benchmarks

**Change parts of a hashref, using "slice" vs writing each key-value "by hand"**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Storable qw(dclone);
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $runfor = shift // 3;  # second to run-for, see cmpthese(...)

my $data = {
    one => [10..12], two => { a => 1, b => 2 },
    more => 'some',
};
my $slice = {  # use this to change $data
    one => [2..6], two => { A => 10, B => 20 },
};

sub by_slice {
    my ($data, $slice) = @_; 
    my @keys = keys %$slice;
    @{$data}{@keys} = @{$slice}{@keys};
    return $data;
}

sub by_hand { 
    my ($data, $slice) = @_; 
    for (qw(one two)) {
        $data->{$_} = $slice->{$_}
    }  
    # This can only be faster, but barely
    #$data->{$_} = $slice->{$_}  for qw(one two);
    return $data;
}

my $d1 = dclone $data;
my $d2 = dclone $data;

cmpthese(-$runfor, {
    by_slice => sub { my $res_data = by_slice($data, $slice) },
    by_hand  => sub { my $res_data = by_hand ($data, $slice) },
});
```

Running this for 10 seconds (`progname 10`), on a very old laptop with perl 5.16 (CentOS 7)

```
             Rate by_slice  by_hand
by_slice 709738/s       --     -25%
by_hand  940751/s      33%       --
```

So doing it "by hand" is indeed a bit faster, as guessed but some more.   At least in this simple test-case, but I'd expect that no less (and perhaps more?) with more complex data. A part of this is due to constructing that extra array in the 'slice' case.

**Copying a part of a complex data structure, by hand vs using `Storable`**

Well, this is a no-contest since there is no efficient way to extract a "part" of a hashref, but one has to rebuild it by pulling out wanted key => value pairs and constructing a hashref with them.  Then, while using `Storable` we have to do all that *and* call the function to copy data. Given that by-hand copy *in this case* is very simple it beats the library use hands down (by a factor of 3)

Comparing

```
sub by_lib {
    my ($data) = @_; 
    return dclone( { one => $data->{one}, two => $data->{two} } );
    #return dclone( { map { $_ => $data->{$_} } qw(one two) } ); # little slower
}

sub by_hand { 
    my ($data) = @_; 
    return { 
        one => [ @{ $data->{one} } ],
        two => { %{ $data->{two} } },
    }
}
```

by using them in the benchmark program above yields

```
            Rate  by_lib by_hand
by_lib  157838/s      --    -75%
by_hand 627359/s    297%      --
```

Note added— Just so, I also compared the by-hand-copy with `Storable` for copying the whole data structure -- and the lib is slower by a factor of 2.

Two morals come out of that, for me: with simple data the overheads of a general purpose library (which has to do a lot of extra work for its generality) are beat by the manual copy; and, needing the slice indeed hurts the library use further, going from `x`2 to `x`3.

Speaking of libraries and speed, also see footnote<sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup>†</sup>  There is also `JSON::XS`, which serializes data and comes out about twice as fast as `Storable` in my test. Thus still half the speed of the manual copying, for simple data.

With it you'd need to JSON-encode data for `return`-ing from a sub, and to decode on receiving the return

```
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json decode_json);

sub do_move {
    ...
    return encode_json ...;
}
```

and

```
my $ret = decode_json do_move(...);
```

Comment: Only a subset of `$self` has to be saved and restored. And the arrays and hashes involved are just one level deep and that will probably never change. But I can  depend on the exact version of `Chess::Play` in order to be safe here.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr  Updated with a discussion given the clarification (and edited a little)

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I ran some benchmarks and added them